# Alamofire doing two requests

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm sending some data back after a user logins in with facebook. It seems like Alamofire is doing two requests, instead of just one for some reason:

**Swift code**

```
func loginViewFetchedUserInfo(loginView: FBLoginView!, user: FBGraphUser!) {
    println("loginViewFetchedUserInfo")

    let fb_id: (AnyObject)!         = user.objectForKey("id") as String
    let first_name: (AnyObject)!    = user.objectForKey("first_name") as String
    let last_name: (AnyObject)!     = user.objectForKey("last_name") as String
    let email: (AnyObject)!         = user.objectForKey("email") as String

    let user_data: Dictionary = [
        "fb_id": fb_id,
        "first_name": first_name,
        "last_name": last_name,
        "email": email
    ]

    Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/user/login", parameters: user_data)
        .responseJSON { (_, _, JSON, _) in
            println(JSON)
    } 
}
```

**Console output**

```
loginViewFetchedUserInfo
Optional({
    "status" = "success
})
Optional({
    "status" = "success
})
```

And indeed I get two requests on the server. Any reason why the framework is doing two requests instead of just one?

Answer (score 0):

Is your `loginViewFetchedUserInfo()` function inside a `UIViewController`?
Maybe you are initializing this `UIViewController` or the owner class of the function **twice**.

In my case this was caused because of many instances of the same class using the same Notification Observer name.